# Size of colormap(gray)

Tags: matlab, grayscale, colormap

I read on internet that a greyscale image has 256 possible values . But in matlab when i tried this :-

```
>> a=colormap(gray);
>> whos a
  Name       Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  a         64x3              1536  double
```

It shows that colormap(gray) has only 64 values. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default length of a color map is 64 values.
You can use `a=colormap(gray(256));`, or better use: `a=gray(256);` for 256 values.

In general `colormap` has now special treatment for grey levels.
`colormap` is kind of "Look Up Table" maps "index" to RGB triplet (greyscale triplet means R=G=B).
256 values is sufficient for all possible grey levels, but for covering all the RGB levels (assuming byte per color channel), you need: 256^3 = 16777216 values.

The default 64 values applies 64 samples out of 256 grey levels (there are quantization "gaps" between samples).

Examples:

`gray(2)`
Result: 2 grey levels (0 and 1):
`0     0     0`  (black)
`1     1     1`  (white)

`gray(4)`
Result: 4 grey levels:
`0         0         0`  (black)
`0.3333    0.3333    0.3333`  (dark grey)
`0.6667    0.6667    0.6667`  (light grey)
`1.0000    1.0000    1.0000`  (white)
As you can see, minimum is 0, maximum is 1, and levels in between are 1/3 and 2/3.

Same principle for `gray(64)`...